# It says always I'm not in "sudoers" file!

Tags: debian, ubuntu, sudo, group, usermod

I migrated from Ubuntu-20 to Debian-12, and I can't excute the command `sudo` with my username `my_name` within a fresh installed system.

So, I added `my_name` into "sudo" group(`usermod -aG sudo my_name`) within a root logged-in terminal, and then rebooted my computer.

But it doesn't work, I still get the message like "my_name is not in sudoers file...".

I found a strange thing, i.e. when I issue `groups` command within a terminal window that logged-in as my_name, the "sudo" group name do **NOT** exist in the group list.
But when I execute `groups my_name` with root's permission, the "sudo" group name **DO EXIST** in the group list!

Is this a bug of Debian-12?
Or I missed some action?

Comment: `not in sudoers file` ... it states not in a **file** ... not a group - have a look in `/etc/sudoers` file and the `/etc/sudoers.d` folder

Comment: FYI, when the installer asks you for root password, entering no password would instead configure sudo.

Comment: @JaromandaX thx! I think that It's not necessary to explicitly add `my_name` into /etc/sudoers file, because there is an entry for all members of `sudo` group. Am I right?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks! Maybe I should re-install it again? Oh, No!

Comment: You don't need to re-install again, just configure sudo - as for members of sudo group ... I've never configured it that way, so I can't be sure

Comment: "because there is an entry for all members of sudo group." ... Is there? Have you verified that?

Comment: The fact that `sudo` appears in the output of `groups yourusername` but not `groups` suggests you've not logged out and back in after doing `usermod -aG sudo my_name`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas what's puzzling me is that this conclusion doesn't tally with "_and then rebooted my computer_"

Comment: @muru From what I can see (in the `debian:12` Docker image, after installing `sudo`) is that the `sudo` group is mentioned in a line in the default `sudoers` file: `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` (this is not commented out).  The `sudo` group also exists in `/etc/group` (GID is 27).

Answer (score 1):

Have the `/etc/group` and/or `/etc/gshadow` files been edited manually (outside `usermod`/`groupmod` and similar tools)?

There might be a syntax error that is small enough to be ignored by `groups yourusername` but the PAM libraries that set up your session might be more strict.

Run `grpck` as root to check the syntax of the group files.

You might want to run `pwck` too, although you are certain to get some error messages about system accounts like `lp`, `news`, `uucp`, `list`, `irc` and `gnats` not having a home directory; in most cases, that just means you don't have the respective subsystem/service installed, and is harmless.

Answer (score 0):

1.Log in as root: You need to log in to the root account to be able to make changes to the `sudoers` file. If you have the root password, you can switch to the root user by typing `su` in the terminal and then entering the root password.

1.1 Find `visudo` at `/usr/sbin`.

1.2 Add `/usr/sbin` to your PATH: You can temporarily add `/usr/sbin` to your PATH like this:

```bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

1.3 Run `visudo` with full path:

```bash
/usr/sbin/visudo
```

2. Edit the `sudoers` file: Once logged in as root, use the `visudo` command to safely edit the `sudoers` file. This command opens the `sudoers` file in the default text editor and checks for syntax errors upon saving, which is crucial since a mistake can lock out all sudo access.
3. Add your user to the `sudoers` file: In the `sudoers` file, look for a line that looks like this:

```sql
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Below this line, add a line for your user account like so:

```sql
yourusername    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Replace yourusername with your actual username.

4. Save and exit: After adding your user to the `sudoers` file, save the file and exit the editor. If you're using `visudo` with the default Vim editor, you can do this by typing :wq and then pressing Enter.
5. Log out from root: Once your user has been added, log out from the root user and try using sudo with your regular user account.

Comment: `export` is unnecessary, and once you've added `/usr/sbin` to `PATH`, you don't need that prefix to run `visudo`; but otherwise a good answer, thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem: after giving user X root permission under root account, login back to user X and applying sudo results in "not in sudoers group" despite user can be seen with 'getent group sudo'.

Yet, one can change permissions as well under Gnome settings, Users and groups. That worked for me.